# Add id by group which resets to 1 in R

Tags: r

I'm sure this must be a dupe but I just can't get it to work. I want to add an ID col to a data frame, which resets to 1 for each unique value in one column. Best way to describe is by example:

```
gr1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
gr2 <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4)

df <- data.frame(gr1, gr2)
```

Desired output:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,1,2,2)
df <- cbind(df, id)
```

The id is marking unique values of gr2 within the each subset of gr1. When gr1 changed from A to B, the id resets to 1. I have read this ([Assign an ID based on two columns R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671852/assign-an-id-based-on-two-columns-r)) but that is not what I want. I don't want to add a rank function (I think) because by I want my ties all to have the same id within gr1 e.g.

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(gr1) %>% mutate(id=rank(gr2, ties.method="max"))
```

Banging my head against the wall. Any pointers would be a great help.

Comment: using `data.table` : `setDT(df)[,id:=rleid(gr2),gr1]`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Do you want to post as an answer?

Comment: `1 + gr2 - ave(gr2, gr1, FUN = min)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `?rleid` from the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, id := rleid(gr2), by = gr1]
> df
   gr1 gr2 id
1:   A   1  1
2:   A   1  1
3:   A   2  2
4:   B   3  1
5:   B   4  2
6:   B   4  2
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this which uses `ave` to perform the grouping and `factor` to reassign sequential levels from 1.  Note that `ave` automatically converts the factor back to numeric because gr2 is numeric and it makes the result consistent.   No packages are used.

```
df2 <- transform(df, gr2 = ave(gr2, gr1, FUN = factor))
```

giving:

```
> df2
  gr1 gr2
1   A   1
2   A   1
3   A   2
4   B   1
5   B   2
6   B   2
```

It returns a data frame with factor and numeric columns:

```
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ gr1: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 2 2 2
 $ gr2: num  1 1 2 1 2 2
```

Comment: Just trying this on my real data set. It seems to return the factor itself rather than an id. I will try and post some real data.

Comment: Not on the data provided in the question.  Maybe your data frame has a factor as gr2 rather than numeric.  If so, convert it to numeric first so that it corresponds to what was posted.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thank you also.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
df %>%
  group_by(gr1) %>%
  mutate(id=as.numeric(factor(gr2)))
```

Comment: This also worked perfectly, thank you.