# Add ordered ID for each group by date

Tags: r, data.table, rank

I want to add an ordered ID (by date) to each group in a data frame. I can do this using dplyr ([R - add column that counts sequentially within groups but repeats for duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895860/r-add-column-that-counts-sequentially-within-groups-but-repeats-for-duplicates)):

```
# Example data
date <- rep(c("2016-10-06 11:56:00","2016-10-05 11:56:00","2016-10-05 11:56:00","2016-10-07 11:56:00"),2)
date <- as.POSIXct(date)
group <- c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4))    
df <- data.frame(group, date)

# dplyr - dense_rank
df2 <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
       mutate(m.test=dense_rank(date))

   group                date m.test
  <fctr>              <dttm>  <int>
1      A 2016-10-06 11:56:00      2
2      A 2016-10-05 11:56:00      1
3      A 2016-10-05 11:56:00      1
4      A 2016-10-07 11:56:00      3
5      B 2016-10-06 11:56:00      2
6      B 2016-10-05 11:56:00      1
7      B 2016-10-05 11:56:00      1
8      B 2016-10-07 11:56:00      3
```

So my new column `m.test` ranks each `group` by `date`. If I use `rleid` and `data.table`, it doesn't seem to work (05/10 ranked after 06/10):

```
df3 <- setDT(df)[, m.test := rleid(date), by = group]

   group                date m.test
1:     A 2016-10-06 11:56:00      1
2:     A 2016-10-05 11:56:00      2
3:     A 2016-10-05 11:56:00      2
4:     A 2016-10-07 11:56:00      3
5:     B 2016-10-06 11:56:00      1
6:     B 2016-10-05 11:56:00      2
7:     B 2016-10-05 11:56:00      2
8:     B 2016-10-07 11:56:00      3
```

Am I getting the syntax wrong?

Comment: The `data.table` equivalent of dplyr's `dense_rank(...)` is `frank(..., ties.method = "dense")`, afaik

Comment: Thanks. I was getting confused from the answer to this question I originally asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008864/add-id-by-group-which-resets-to-1-in-r). I assume that rleid doesn't work for date in this case.

Comment: Do you want to post an answer.

Comment: No, but you can answer you own question (or delete it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @docendo discimus, the correct way to do this with `data.table` is `frank(..., ties.method = "dense")`:

```
df4 <- setDT(df)[, m.test := frank(date, ties.method = "dense"), by = group]
```